# Equivalence of first order logic formulas

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How do we can conclude that two first order logic formulas are equivalent. As long as this problem should be undecidable I would like to know is there any semi-decidable technique? Does Tableau Method or Resolution  work in here?

As an example $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\forall z \forall x \exists y (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x))$ , Where this $z$ came from?

---

UPDATE:

As [Mauro ALLEGRANZA](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/108274/mauro-allegranza) pointed out in the comments, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent if $\neg(\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)$ is inconsistent. in other words

$$
 \begin{align}
 &\neg(\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)\\
 &=\neg((\phi \rightarrow\psi) \land (\psi \rightarrow\phi))\\
 &=(\neg(\phi \rightarrow\psi) \vee \neg(\psi \rightarrow\phi))\\
 &=(\phi \land \neg\psi) \vee (\psi\land\neg\phi)\\
\end{align}
$$

if we conclude that for any $\phi$ and $\psi$ the formula $(\phi \land \neg\psi) \vee (\psi\land\neg\phi)$ is inconsistent then $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent. Using Tableau Method it creates to branches one for $(\phi \land \neg\psi)$ in the left side and one for $(\psi\land\neg\phi)$ in the right side.

I tried the left side in the following way but it didn't lead to a closed tree, is there something wrong?

$1. \exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$

$2. \neg \forall z \forall x \exists y (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x))$

$3. \exists z \exists x \forall y \neg (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x))$ --- from 2

$4. \forall y \neg (R(a,y) \lor \neg P(b))$ --- from 3, eliminating z and x (a,b are new)

$5. \forall y (\neg R(a,y) \land P(b))$ --- from 4

$6. P(c) \rightarrow \forall x R(x,d)$ --- from 1, eliminating x,y (c,d are new)

$6L. \neg P(c)$

$6R. \forall x R(x,d)$

$6R1. R(a,d)$

$6R2. \neg R(a,d) \land P(b)$ -- from 5

$6R3. \neg R(a,d)$ -- from 6R2

$6R4. P(b)$ -- from 6R2

$6R \bigotimes\bigotimes$ $R(a,d)$ and $\neg R(a,d)$ appeared in right side so it is closed

But in the left side (I mean $6L$) we have $\neg P(c)$ since there is no universal quantifier on $P$, there is no way to get $P(c)$ so the left side is not closed, it means the tree is not closed so the two original formulas are not equivalent! while [Mauro ALLEGRANZA](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/108274/mauro-allegranza) proved they are equivalent.

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?!!

Comment: Step 6 is wrong; first you have to apply the $\to$ rule, because the main connective is $\to$ separating the two branches, and then apply the quantifier rules : **one at the time**, i.e. first on the branch with $\lnot \exists P(x)$ and then on the other branch with ∀x∃yR(x,y) that has ∀x as outer quantifier and you cannot skip it...

Comment: If I do what you said, then it results $\forall \neg P(x)$ and there will be a contradiction with line number $4$ so this branch is a contradiction as well. I didn't know that we must apply the connective first, then applying the quantifier rules, that works.thanks a lot.

Comment: When you "unpack" 1) you have to branch for $\to$; on the left you will find $\lnot ∃xP(x)$ and you have to apply the rule for $\lnot \exists$ that do **not** need a new variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can prove it with "usual" proof systems : *Resolution*, *Tableaux* or with *Natural Deduction* :

1) $∀z∀x∃y(R(z,y)∨¬P(x))$ --- premise

2) $∃xP(x)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $P(w)$ --- assumed [b] for $\exists$-elimination

4) $∃y(R(z,y)∨¬P(w))$ --- from 1) by $\forall$-elimination twice

5) $R(z,y)∨¬P(w)$ --- assumed [c] for $\exists$-elimination

6) $P(w) \to R(z,y)$ --- from 5) by *tautological equivalence* : $(p \to q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor q)$

7) $R(z,y)$ --- from 3) and 6) by $\to$-elimination

8) $\exists yR(z,y)$ --- from 7) by $\exists$-introduction

9) $\forall x \exists yR(x,y)$ --- from 8) by $\forall$-introduction : $x$ is not *free* in any "open" assumptions

$y$ is not free in 9); thus, we can apply $\exists$-elimination with 4), 5) and 9) and conclude with :

10) $\forall x \exists yR(x,y)$, discharging assumption [c].

In the same way, from 2), 3) and 10), discharging assumption [b] and concluding with :

11) $\forall x \exists yR(x,y)$.

Finally :

> $∃xP(x) \to \forall x \exists yR(x,y)$ --- from 2) and 11) by $\to$-introduction, discharging assumption [a].

With a final application of $\to$-introduction we conclude with :
$∀z∀x∃y(R(z,y)∨¬P(x)) \to (∃xP(x) \to ∀x∃yR(x,y))$.

Comment: Thanks you very much, From what I know Tableaux Method is used to show whether a set of formulas are inconsistent then we are looking for closed paths. if the tree is closed then the formulas are inconsistent. I would like to know how closed paths are relevant to equivalence of formulas?

Comment: @Drupalist - $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is simply : $(\phi \to \psi) \land (\psi \to \phi)$. Thus apply Tableaux to *negation* of the last formula and if all paths will close then the original formula is *valid*.

Comment: So $\phi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent if $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ and $\neg (\psi \rightarrow \phi)$ are inconsistent, right?

Comment: @Drupalist - YES.

Comment: Thank you very much, your useful comments and answers  are very helpful for me.

Comment: I updated the question would you please take a look at it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to write down the tree :

$1. \exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)$ --- premise

$2. \neg \forall z \forall x \exists y (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x))$ --- the negation of the conclusion

$3. \exists z \exists x \forall y \neg (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x))$ --- from 2

$4. \forall y \neg (R(a,y) \lor \neg P(b))$ --- from 3, by rule for $\exists$, with $a,b$  new

$5. \forall y (\neg R(a,y) \land P(b))$ --- from 4

$6_L. \neg \exists xP(x)$ --- from 1, by rule for $\to$

$6_R. \forall x \exists yR(x,y)$ --- from 1, by rule for $\to$

Now I'll expand the left branch :

$7. \neg P(a)$ --- from $6_L$, by the rule for $\neg \exists$

$8. \neg P(b)$ --- from $6_L$, by the rule for $\neg \exists$ : we have to use all the constants already introduced

$9. \neg R(a,a) \land P(b)$ --- from 5, by the rule for $\forall$

$10. \neg R(a,b) \land P(b)$ --- from 5, by the rule for $\forall$ : : we have to use all the constants already introduced

Now, applying the $\land$ rule to both $9, 10$ we have :

$11. \neg R(a,a)$

$12. \neg R(a,b)$

$13. P(b)$

and the path closes by $8$ and $13$.

Now I'll expand the right branch :

$14. \exists yR(a,y)$ --- from $6_R$, by the rule for $\forall$

$15. \exists yR(b,y)$ --- from $6_R$, by the rule for $\forall$ : we have to use all the constants already introduced

$16. R(a,c)$ --- from 14, $c$ new

$17. R(a,d)$ --- from 15, $d$ new

Now, as in the left branch, we have to analyze 5 : as above the rule for $\forall$ must be applied to all the constants already introduced : $a,b,c,d$. Thus, the path will contain :

$18. P(b)$

$19. \neg R(a,a)$

$20. \neg R(a,b)$

$21. \neg R(a,c)$

$22. \neg R(a,d)$

and also this path closes.

Both paths are closed, showing that the premise and the negation of the conclusion are *inconsistent*, i.e. that:

> > $$(\exists x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y R(x,y)) \to (\forall z \forall x \exists y (R(z,y) \lor \neg P(x)))$$

is *valid*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed to use all the constants already introduced.

Comment: In a first order logic formula there are formulas which they have no $\exists$ quantifier, all we have is $\forall$. Since we have to replace $\forall$ quantifiers with already defined constant (via eliminating $\exists$), when there is no $\exists$ then what constant should be replaced with $\forall$?

Comment: @Drupalist - if you have to apply the $\forall$ rule first and **no** constants are already available, you are licensed to introduced a new one. This is consistent with the "standard" assumption of first-order logic semantics that the doamin of interpretation is not-empty, i.e. there is always at least one objcet in it.